# Use reverse to pass parameters between views in django

Tags: django, form-submit, reverse, argument-passing

So i am trying to pass a variable from one view to another, after a successful POST form submission, using reverse, thus:

```
url = "%s?model_class=Attributes" % reverse('Directories:edit_models')
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

model_class is not a form field but a simple variable I created inside my view. After redirection the url is displayed correctly, as specified in my url variable (.../?model_class=Attributes). As a result, in the second view I now try to access the variable  using the following code:

```
mvar = request.POST.get('model_class')
```

but when I try to render `mvar` in my template or print it, it says model_class is not defined.

Is my code wrong or should i change my approach of passing parameters between views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `mvar = request.GET.get('model_class')`. As far as I know on redirect you'll retrieve new url via `GET` request, not `POST`.

Comment: definitely a redirect is always a GET request